# Cardinality of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with fixed asymptotic density

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

For a set $S\subset \mathbb{N}$, let

$$a(S)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\#\{s\in S\>|\>s\le n\}}{n}$$

be the [limiting asymptotic density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of $S$ in the natural numbers if the limit exists, and $a(S)=0$ if it does not.

Now take $0<\alpha<1$ and let

$$A_\alpha = \{S\subset \mathbb{N}\>|\>a(S)=\alpha\}$$

be the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with asymptotic density $\alpha$.

**Is $A_\alpha$ countable?**

Comment: I wonder if you can associate this with a probability measure or something like that, on the Cantor space, or the Baire space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For each $n\in\mathbb N$ choose one element from the set $\{2n-1,2n\}$. Each of the $2^{\aleph_0}$ sets you can get this way has asymptotic density $\frac12$.

**P.S.** More generally: If $S$ has density $\alpha$ and $T$ has density zero, then the symmetric difference $S\triangle T$ has density $\alpha$. Of course there are continuum many sets of density zero, e.g., the subsets of a given infinite set of density zero. Thus, by fixing $S$ and varying $T$, we get continuum many sets of density $\alpha$.

Comment: Also, by adding regular gaps or extra elements between pairs in that pattern, you can force the density to be anything between $0$ and $1$ (inclusive).

Comment: Cool answer. To put it intuitively: The sets of even and odd numbers can be "mixed" in an uncountable number of ways without altering their density.

Comment: Better yet, just take any set with density $\alpha$ and flip the elements at $n^2$ positions - all the sets you get by this process will have the same density as the original set.

Comment: The last argument is not really complete since for fixed S, the map that sends T to the symmetric difference of S and T need not be injective.

Comment: @JonathanHole Of course the map $T\mapsto S\Delta T$ is injective. If $S\Delta T_1=S\Delta T_2$ then $$T_1=\emptyset\Delta T_1=(S\Delta S)\Delta T_1=S\Delta(S\Delta T_1)=S\Delta(S\Delta T_2)=(S\Delta S)\Delta T_2=\emptyset\Delta T_2=T_2.$$ $\langle\mathcal P(\mathbb N),\Delta\rangle$ is an Abelian group.

Comment: Sorry, you're right of course